# Drupal 6 "Access denied" on page content after moving ftp+sql

Tags: drupal, feed

I moving my **Drupal 6** website on a local wamp install to work on (same php and apache version with the domain in etc\hosts 127.0.01 etc...).

But I get a **Drupal error "Access denied" on ALL Pages**. (home /user /login etc.)
I have just the header menu and the bottom of the pages displaying correctly. And between : the content is "Access denied".

It's been over 2 days I'm looking for a solution. Do you have an idea or getting a solution for the same problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Version : PHP 5.3.3 / Apache 2.2.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : In order :

- SERVER : verify mod_rewrite enable on Apache server
- DB : clean session table
- BROWSER : clear cache session cookies